# Публикация проекта Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Собираюсь опубликовать проект на C++, для удобства и быстрого начала работы с ним хочу прикрепить проект Visual Studio. Какие файлы нужно положить, можно ли как-то вынести их в директорию, например `msvc`? Какие файлы класть не надо? Может быть можно автоматически генерировать файлы проектов? Там много настроек, где-то, возможно пути прописаны абсолютно или ещё какая-то информация, которую публиковать вообще не нужно.

Comment: самый минимум - все *.c, *.cpp, *.h, *.hpp. Также файл проекта (Он зависит от версии студии).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**VS 2012 и новее**

Надо: `.sln` `.vcxproj` `.vcxproj.filters`

Не надо: `.suo` `.sdf` `.opensdf` `*.user` и результаты сборки (Release, Debug)

(еще, если настроено локально сохранять прекомпилированные заголовки, папку `ipch` не надо коммитить)

**VS 2008 и старее**

Надо: `.sln` `.vcproj`

Не надо: `.suo` `*.user` `.ncb` и результаты сборки (Release, Debug)